# Macports select default Python interpreter for executing scripts?

Tags: python, macos, macports

I used `python_select`, it seems like it does not change the default python for executing scripts, for instance `django-admin.py runserver` (without python in front).

How do i change this?

Comment: I think this might be better placed on SuperUser...

Comment: It's possible that it can be overridden by a `#!` first line in the .py files.

Comment: Yes, one can override it by a `#!`, indeed, but the OP's question is specifically about the default Python interpreter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is `/usr/bin/python`, which is usually earlier in the path (has a higher precedence) than MacPort's binary folder (`/opt/local/bin/python`). The `python_select` script changes only `/opt/local/bin/python`, so you have to make sure there is no other `python` binary on your path taking precedence over it.

Solution (as root):

```
mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python.orig
ln -s /opt/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python
port select --set python python26
```

Make sure you replace `python26` in the third line with your intended Python version.

It worked for me a few days ago with MacPort 2.0.0. If you have an older MacPorts library, then you should either upgrade it or use `python_select` instead of `port select --set python`.

Comment: A simpler and safer approach is to put /opt/local/bin earlier in your PATH.  

To do this once you can do the following in bash shell:  

```export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH```  

Or edit  ~/.bash_profile and add the line to the end of the file.  

It's generally a bad idea to modify the system's Python as if you break it, you may break any utilities or tools on your Mac that use the system's Python.  

Edit: formatting.

Comment: @MickT: I did what you suggested, because I think it's a better approach. I can verify that `/opt/local/bin` is at the top of my `PATH` variable, yet when I type `which python`, it gives a listing starting with `/usr/local/bin/python`. Any idea why `which` is giving a different order than the `PATH`?

Comment: @jvriesem If ```/usr/local/bin/``` is first in your path then ```/usr/local/bin/python``` will be first Python found. Am I misunderstanding something? If I am, please post the output of the following:  


echo $PATH

Comment: I'm still applying this solution up to OS X 10.11 El Capitan but I have to disable SIP in order for this to work. Not sure for how long Apple will allow us to disable this protection, which is not ideal.